# Caml Query not applying to my list requests

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, javascript, caml

I have a SharePoint Application that needs to data from lists to be inserted into  elements.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
Collection.List.DropDown = function (listTitle, element) {
//listTitle = "DropDownLists";

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("DropDownLists");

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_viewXml("   <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ListType' /><Value Type='Text'>Customer Class</Value></Eq></Where>");

                        /*<ViewFields>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='ListType' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='ListDefault' />" +
                        "</ViewFields>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='ListType' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                        "</OrderBy>" +
                        "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ListType' />" +
                                "<Value Type='Text'>" + listTitle + "</Value>" +
                            "</Eq>" +
                        "</Where>");

                        /*"<Query>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                                "<Eq>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name=\"ListType\"/>" +
                                    "<Value Type=\"Text\">\"" + listTitle + "\"</Value>" +
                                "</Eq>" +
                            "</Where>" +
                            "<OrderBy>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"ListValue\"/>" +
                            "</OrderBy>" +
                        "</Query>");*/



var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

//clientContext.load(this.collListItem, "Include(Id, ListType, ListValue, ListDefault)");

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function (sender, args) {
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfo += "<option id=\"" + oListItem.get_id() + "\" " + (oListItem.get_item("ListDefault") == true ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") + ">" + oListItem.get_item("Title") + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = listItemInfo.toString();

    },
    function (sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
```

};

The lists return successfully, but the CAML Query is not working, it keeps returning all the items withing the list.

In the code example you can see all the different CAML Queries I tried.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try starting the caml query within tags <View><Query><Where><Eq>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [this example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx), you need to wrap with `<View>` tags, as shown below:

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```